# Update Clob column in Oracle

Tags: xml, oracle, clob

I have an table with name ABC which has CLOB data. I want to update the column to insert string in specific position in this Clob column.

String to be inserted :

```
<nv_pair>
<name identifier="XYZ"></name>
<value identifier="XYZ"></value>
</nv_pair>
```

Clob Data :

```
<form> <nv_pair></nv_pair> <nv_pair></nv_pair><nv_pair></nv_pair><nv_pair></nv_pair></form>
```

Position to be inserted : Just Before `</form>`

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at DBMS_LOB package.

BTW, it might be worth exploring the possibility of abandoning CLOB and using Oracle's built-in XML capabilities (I'm not familiar with that, though).

Comment: +1 for the xmltype suggestion although it will depend on the database version whether it's possible (and advisable) to switch.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on which version of Oracle you have, you can use the regexp_replace function:

```
update abc
set clob_val =
  regexp_replace(clob_val,
                 '^(.+)(</form>)',
                 '\1<nv_pair><name identifier="XYZ"></name><value identifier="XYZ">/value>/nv_pair>\2')
where ...
```